Почему не отображается ShippingOption на мобильных устройствах aiogram 3?
Разрабатываю бота для своего интернет-магазина. Дошел до момента осуществление платежей. Вызываю окно платежа(bot.send_invoice()). Далее обрабатываю shipping_query, который должен выводить доступные способы доставки по РФ, если страна не РФ, то сообщаем об этом.
# убрал из кода переменные, чтобы не отвлекали. 
@router.callback_query(F.data.startswith('order_'))
async def order(callback: CallbackQuery):
    item_id = callback.data.split('_')[1]
    size = callback.data.split('_')[2]

    msg = await bot.send_invoice(
        chat_id=callback.message.chat.id,
        title=title,
        description=description,
        payload=str(item.id),
        provider_token=PAY_TOKEN,
        currency='RUB',
        prices=[
            LabeledPrice(
                label=item.name,
                amount=59900
            )
        ],
        start_parameter='startBot',
        photo_url=DOMAIN + photo[0],
        photo_height=height,
        photo_width=width,
        photo_size=length,
        need_phone_number=True,
        need_shipping_address=True,
        request_timeout=60,
        is_flexible=True,
        reply_markup=await kb_order(item_id, item.retail_price, item.catalog),
    )

@router.shipping_query()
async def process_shipping_query(shipping_query: ShippingQuery):
    shipping_options = [
        ShippingOption(id='one', title='One', prices=[LabeledPrice(label='One', amount=10000)]),
        ShippingOption(id='two', title='Two', prices=[LabeledPrice(label='Two', amount=11000)])
    ]

    if shipping_query.shipping_address.country_code != 'RU':
        return await bot.answer_shipping_query(
                                shipping_query_id=shipping_query.id, 
                                ok=False, 
                                error_message='We do not work in this country')

    await bot.answer_shipping_query(
                    shipping_query_id=shipping_query.id, 
                    ok=True, 
                    shipping_options=shipping_options)

На ПК все работает как надо. На мобильных устройствах не отображается shipping_options ни на android, ни на iphone.
Пробовал убирать условие и обрабатывать любую страну - без результата.
Еще если на iphone выбрать 1 любую страну, то больше изменить ее не получается, потому что все остальные страны куда-то пропадают. Чем это исправить тоже не понятно.
Телеграм обновлен, логи ничего не говорят, ошибок никаких не показывает.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.
